# Fancybox 2 breaking in PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, cordova, fancybox

I'm using [Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) inside of a PhoneGap application. For those who don't know PhoneGap, at it's most basic, it allows you to use the WebKit engine to develop an HTML-based app.

I'm using Fancybox to display images and it is working great in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but as soon as I compile it in Xcode to an iPad app, the follow error appears:

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```

However, what'd odd about this error is that it disappears after two, three, four or five tries, but never after the first.

I am assuming it is trying to use Ajax to load the content, which is not possible when there is no web server. I've tried adjusting the settings, but to no avail. Does anyone have any thoughts or experience on this?

```
$(".image-nav a").fancybox({
    arrows      : false,
    autoCenter  : false,
    autoSize    : false,
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    closeSpeed  : 150,
    closeClick  : true,
    closeBtn    : false,
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    openSpeed   : 300,
    padding     : 0,
    type        : 'image',

    helpers: {
        overlay : {
            // use 0.0 opacity instead of overlay : null
            // because we don't want the user to accidentally
            // press a nav button
            //
            opacity : 0.0
        }
    }
});

$(".image-nav.thumbs a").fancybox({
    arrows      : false,
    autoCenter  : false,
    autoSize    : false,
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    closeSpeed  : 150,
    closeClick  : true,
    closeBtn    : false,
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    openSpeed   : 300,
    padding     : 0,
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    type        : 'image',

    helpers: {
        overlay : {
            // use 0.0 opacity instead of overlay : null
            // because we don't want the user to accidentally
            // press a nav button
            //
            opacity : 0.0,
            speedIn : 0,
        },
        thumbs : {
            width   : 100,
            height  : 80
        }
    }
});
```